# AWS DataBrew - ValueError: Could not parse datatype: decimal(1,-3317)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-databrew

I am running a DataBrew recipe job on a pipe-delimited file and received this error: *ValueError: Could not parse datatype: decimal(1,-3317)*

I have successfully run this DataBrew job with similar files (i.e., files from the same client) many times and have never had this error before. I have also manually inspected the file and the data types of all the columns are no different than previous months.

A Google search has provided me with few helpful answers and hence, I wanted to know if anyone had an idea why this error is being raised?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used to see this issue for values with negative exponents on it like `1.23456e-78`. This issue is no longer happening, probably it is fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30747800)